# Show Duplicate Values

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I Have a table (#tempX) below.

```
BoxNumber | Location 
----------|----------
ABC123    |Nowra
ABC123    |Sydney
KLM222    |Melbourne
XYZ444    |Karatha
XYZ444    |Mirabooka
XYZ444    |Logan
PQR888    |Brisbane
```

I need to find the duplicate and display them.

```
BoxNumber | Location 
----------|----------
ABC123    |Nowra
ABC123    |Sydney
XYZ444    |Karatha
XYZ444    |Mirabooka
XYZ444    |Logan
```

I used the query below (you can copy and paste it to your SQL server) however it doesn't give me what I'm looking for. It gives me blank table as a result.

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempX') Is Not Null)

Drop Table #tempX

create table #tempX (box varchar(max) ,location varchar(max))

insert into #tempX (box,location)
values ('ABC123','Nowra'),('ABC123','Sydney'),('KLM222', 'Melbourne'),('XYZ444','Karatha'),('XYZ444','Mirabooka'),('XYZ444','Logan'),('PQR888','Brisbane')

--select * from #tempx

select distinct Box, Location, count(*) from #tempX
group by Box, Location
having count(*) > 1
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012. Thanks all.

Comment: do you still need help?

Comment: Yes please Cookie Monster if you have any idea for this. Thanks.

Comment: try this:  Select BoxNumber,Location,Count(*)
    from #tempX
    Group By BoxNumber
    Having Count(*) >1

Comment: alright i solved it, look at the posted answer, if it's correct pls mark it as solved and upvote it

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are trying to find duplicate values of Box **AND** Location.

```
Select a.* from 
    #tempX a join 
            (   
            select Box from #tempX
            group by Box
            having count(Box) > 1
            ) b on a.box = b.box
order by a.box, a.Location
```

or :

```
select box, Location 
    from #tempX
    where box in (select Box from #tempX group by Box having count(Box) > 1)
order by box, Location
```

Comment: The 2nd query won't even execute. You can't select 2 values in the subquery.

Comment: Even in 1st query, `count(box)` is not needed.A `GROUP BY` is enough for using `count(box)` in `HAVING`

Comment: I appreciate you effort to edit your answer +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    create table #tmp (BoxNumber VARCHAR(25),Location  VARCHAR(25))

    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('ABC123','Nowra')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('ABC123','Sydney')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('KLM222','Melbourne')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('XYZ444','Karatha')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('XYZ444','Mirabooka')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('XYZ444','Logan')
    INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('PQR888','Brisbane')



    ;with cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by BoxNumber order by BoxNumber) as [rank],* From #tmp
    )


    SELECT DISTINCT t.* from #tmp t
    JOIN cte c on t.BoxNumber=c.BoxNumber and c.[rank]>1

    /*

        -- OR (BELOW Query also returns the same result)

        SELECT * from #tmp
        WHERE BoxNumber in 
        (   
                SELECT  BoxNumber from cte where [rank]>1
        )

    */

    Drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
   select *
      from #tempX 
     where  Box in   
           ( select Box
               from #tempX 
              group by Box
             having count(*) > 1 )
```

Comment: There's no difference between this and EagerToLearn's answer.

Comment: What's the difference?? Even his query works as expected.

Comment: His second query uses order by box, Location. I use group by. How is it the same?

Comment: order by doesn't make any difference in records retrieved. It just makes sure the result is  ordered properly.

Comment: Well OP said his answer is not working so I tried to help out, was that so hard?